# How to check if a string has consecutive whitespace

Tags: java, regex, string

How do i check if a string has more than 1 consecutive whitespace.
Like:

```
I support Global Warming
```

returns true, but:

```
I  support     Global  Warming
```

returns false.

Comment: So basically you want to check if a string has two consecutive spaces anywhere in the string?

Comment: I updated your question to be "consecutive whitespace", which I think is what you're asking.  (The first example contains three whitespaces, one between each word.)  If that's not what you're asking, please edit back.

Answer (score 4):

This will cover any whitespace:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{javaWhitespace}{2,}");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher("I Support Foo Bar");
if (m.find()) {
   System.out.println("More than one space found");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
boolean containsMultipleWhitespaces = str.contains("  ");
```

Comment: May not be what the user asks, but I would first trim the string, to avoid false positives with leading or trailing whitespaces.

Comment: @Luciano: hard to see, but the OP added trailing whitespace so it's difficult to tell whether they intend trailing whitespace to be matched or not.

Comment: Hmm, maybe im miscontruing the OP's post, but @ante's code sample only detects 2 consecutive spaces in a String.

Comment: "   ".contains("  ") == true  // a 3-space string contains a 2-space string

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your meaning, just going by your original example.
(just ignore if its misinterpreted)
Original quote:
`"Like: "I support Global Warming" returns true, but "I support Global Warming " returns false."`

check whitespace at the end only: `^(?!.*\s$)`

check whitespace at both ends: `^(?!\s|.*\s$)`

check whitespace at both ends and require non-whitespace
in body: : `^(?=.*\S)(?!\s|.*\s$)`

Using `^(?=.*\S)(?!\s|.*\s$)`
"I support Global Warming" - matches (true)
"I support Global Warming " - does not match (false)
" I support Global Warming" - does not match (false)
"" - does not match (false)